# I am trying to use switch case from alphabet to a number, but it seems not working

Tags: javascript, string, variables, switch-statement, var

I am trying to use switch case from alphabet to digits, however, it seems not working.

```
    var y;

    switch (y) {
        case y = "A":
            y = 10;

            break;
        default:

    }


    console.log(y+Part1End);
```

Comment: This is the incorrect syntax for `switch`. Check how to actually use it and try again.

Comment: @vlaz I appreciate that you want to help. Can you take this ahed by posting the correct code in the answers section.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch syntax is incorrect. If you look at the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) you'll see the correct syntax. However, this should work:

```
var y;
switch (y) {
    case "A":
        y = "10";
        break;
    default:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a comparison in the case. So the value of `case y == "A"` is a boolean which doesn't match the given parameter `(y)`.

Change `switch (y)` to `switch (true)`:

```
var y;
switch (true) {
    case y == "A":
        y = 10;

        break;
    default:

}
```

Comment: Why not just use `"A"` as the case instead of inverting to `switch (true)`? The latter construct is indeed _possible_ but in most circumstances it's not a good idea.